# Changing the last value of a nested array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have the following structure

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "mem_id" : M002,
    "email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "event_type" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "MT",
            "count" : 2,
            "language" : [ 
                {
                    "cast" : [ 
                        {
                            "name" : "Some Name 1",
                            "count" : 2
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name" : "Some Name 2",
                            "count" : 4
                        }, 
                    ],
                    key: 0
                },
                {
                    "cast" : [ 
                        {
                            "name" : "Some Name 3",
                            "count" : 2
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name" : "Some Name 4",
                            "count" : 4
                        }, 
                    ],
                    key: 1
                }

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to change the value of "Some Name 2". actually it's always going to be the last element of the nested array "cast".

I'm searching for the key value to find the correct index of the language array so I have the positional value.

The question is how can I change the last value of the nested array?

Can I do something like that? (Python)

```
  const query = {_id: 2, 'event_type.language.key': 0};
  const updateQuery = {$set: {'event_type.language.$.cast.-1.name': "Some Name 4"}};

  User.update(
    query,
    updateQuery,
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(404).end();
      } else {
        res.status(200).end();
      }
    }
  );
```